# React Router 4 is not passing the params to a container

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have the following URL:

```
http://localhost:4400/rate/e0166d
```

Which triggers this route in App.jsx:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/rate/:token" layout={MainLayout} component={Rate} />
```

Here is Rate.js:

```
import React from 'react';

class Rate extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Rate</h1>
        <h2>{this.props.match.params.token}</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Rate;
```

This is outputting:

```
<h2></h2>
```

Why isn't the token being displayed in the `<h2>` tag?

Comment: This worked `this.props.match.params.token` ... am I supposed to be making render pass props like this: `render(props) {` or is it normal to use `this.props` in the render func?

Comment: this.props is typical syntax for a react component.

Comment: you can send match  to the `render ({match})`

Comment: @Abdoutelb how so?

Comment: Abdoutelb is using object deconstruction to grab the value of match from whatever the argument of render is ( which is props in this case )

Comment: `render({match}) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Rate</h1>
        <h2>{match.params.token}</h2>
      </div>
    )`
this is how i am grab params

Comment: `<PrivateRoute>` is not a react-router v4 component. Can you provide your code for the `<PrivateRoute>` component?

Comment: I was using react-devise which is where that complement came from. It also had a bug which caused this issue which is now fixed. This now works as expected.